# how to obtain a filtered signal by using scipy.signal.butter & lfilter?

Tags: python, filter, scipy, signal-processing

I have a program whose purpose is to filter a noisy signal using butterworth filter. the code is listed below. The program cannot be complied because I did something wrong at the last step "y = butter_bandpass_filter(v_numbers, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=6)".
What i want to get are three plots: 1.input signal in time domain, 2. butterworth filter in frquency domain. 3. output filtered signal in time domain.

### Can you help me solve the problem? Thank you.

```
from scipy.signal import butter, lfilter
def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
nyq = 0.5 * fs
low = lowcut / nyq
high = highcut / nyq
b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
return b, a


def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
y = lfilter(b, a, data)
return y


if __name__ == "__main__":
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import freqz

# Sample rate and desired cutoff frequencies (in Hz).

fs = 5000.0
lowcut = 0.0
highcut = 2000.0

# Plot the frequency response for a few different orders.
plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
for order in [3, 6, 9]:
b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
w, h = freqz(b, a, worN=2000)
plt.plot((fs * 0.5 / np.pi) * w, abs(h), label="order = %d" % order)

plt.plot([0, 0.5 * fs], [np.sqrt(0.5), np.sqrt(0.5)],
         '--', label='sqrt(0.5)')
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Gain')
plt.grid(True)
plt.legend(loc='best')

# Filter a noisy signal.
T = 0.9004
nsamples = T * fs
t = np.linspace(0, T, nsamples, endpoint=False)
a = 0.02
f0 =600.0
# Plot the frequency response for a few different orders.
f = open('NIRS_data.txt','r')
number_string = f.readline()
v_numbers = []
while number_string != '':
numbers = number_string.split()
for number in numbers:

    v_numbers.append( number )
number_string = f.readline()

plt.figure()
plt.clf()
plt.plot(t,v_numbers, label = 'Noisy signal') 

y = butter_bandpass_filter(v_numbers, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=6)
plt.plot(t, y, label='Filtered signal (%g Hz)')
plt.xlabel('time (seconds)')

plt.show()
```

A part of txt file is shown below. The amount of datas is 4502.

8.2178200e-02
   8.2173600e-02
   8.2129400e-02
   8.2209000e-02
   8.2183000e-02
   8.2098900e-02
   8.2162500e-02
   8.2157700e-02
   8.2177900e-02
   8.2177600e-02
   8.2088400e-02
   8.2142900e-02
   8.2179600e-02
   8.2159200e-02
   8.2144800e-02
   8.2139000e-02
   8.2121200e-02
   8.2157900e-02
   8.2142600e-02
   8.2190600e-02
   8.2129500e-02
   8.2125800e-02
   8.2097500e-02
   8.2087300e-02
   8.2206800e-02
   8.2175400e-02
   8.2183300e-02
   8.2197400e-02
   8.2129500e-02
   8.2101600e-02
   8.2117800e-02
   8.2125900e-02
   8.2131300e-02
   8.2107600e-02
   8.2146900e-02
   8.2122400e-02
   8.2111800e-02
   8.2156100e-02
   8.2088500e-02
   8.2135300e-02
   8.2119700e-02
   8.2100800e-02
   8.2135700e-02
   8.2126900e-02
   8.2134000e-02
   8.2111000e-02
   8.2101600e-02
   8.2108600e-02
   8.2142900e-02
   8.2091000e-02
   8.2117700e-02
   8.2061400e-02
   8.2085200e-02
   8.2080400e-02
   8.2075400e-02
   8.2064400e-02
   8.2059700e-02
   8.2098200e-02
   8.2077200e-02
   8.2138200e-02
   8.2116300e-02
   8.2092000e-02
   8.2071900e-02
   8.2092500e-02
   8.2056900e-02
   8.2108900e-02
   8.2061300e-02
   8.2064300e-02
   8.2063900e-02
   8.2120600e-02
   8.2049500e-02
   8.2087300e-02
   8.2066800e-02
   8.2074900e-02
   8.2052400e-02
   8.2093200e-02
   8.2061800e-02
   8.2043700e-02
   8.2070500e-02
   8.2056900e-02
   8.2084000e-02
   8.2075900e-02
   8.2065900e-02
   8.2054200e-02
   8.2037400e-02
   8.2040600e-02
   8.2085500e-02
   8.2029000e-02
   8.2057000e-02
   8.2045700e-02
   8.2112600e-02
   8.2068000e-02
   8.2034900e-02
   8.2045200e-02
   8.2046400e-02
   8.2067300e-02
   8.2080500e-02
   8.2021400e-02
   8.2047300e-02
   8.2060200e-02
   8.2042900e-02
   8.2065200e-02
   8.2056100e-02
   8.1990900e-02
   8.2055700e-02
   8.2030300e-02
   8.2103400e-02
   8.2092600e-02
   8.1995200e-02
   8.2075300e-02
   8.2001500e-02
   8.2064000e-02
   8.2033500e-02
   8.2042800e-02
   8.2037400e-02
   8.2002000e-02
   8.2057900e-02
   8.2025100e-02
   8.2038900e-02
   8.2035200e-02
   8.2005700e-02
   8.2016700e-02
   8.2012800e-02
   8.1984900e-02
   8.2066200e-02
   8.2029600e-02
   8.2027400e-02
   8.2012200e-02
   8.2009400e-02
   8.2024900e-02
   8.2038700e-02
   8.2034700e-02
   8.2016200e-02
   8.1964500e-02
   8.2019400e-02
   8.2010500e-02
   8.2004100e-02
   8.2057500e-02
   8.2052300e-02
   8.2004500e-02
   8.1998400e-02
   8.2011600e-02
   8.2038400e-02
   8.2002500e-02
   8.2005700e-02
   8.2065900e-02
   8.1991200e-02
   8.2039900e-02
   8.2028200e-02
   8.2027000e-02
   8.2021300e-02
   8.2019600e-02
   8.2032900e-02
   8.2011700e-02
   8.2017400e-02
   8.2069400e-02
   8.1998400e-02
   8.2059400e-02
   8.1958300e-02
   8.1995800e-02
   8.2018500e-02
   8.1973400e-02
   8.2008800e-02
   8.1995900e-02
   8.1989400e-02
   8.1991800e-02
   8.2000600e-02
   8.2040400e-02
   8.2035700e-02
   8.1987800e-02
   8.2027400e-02
   8.2010800e-02
   8.1991300e-02
   8.1999400e-02
   8.1926800e-02
   8.2021100e-02
   8.1967800e-02
   8.1992600e-02
   8.2022200e-02
   8.1933100e-02
   8.1998900e-02
   8.2004300e-02
   8.1991300e-02
   8.2039500e-02
   8.1998900e-02
   8.2005400e-02
   8.1997600e-02
   8.1954500e-02
   8.2000000e-02
   8.1978000e-02
   8.1990800e-02
   8.1966200e-02
   8.1997400e-02
   8.2028700e-02
   8.1957700e-02
   8.2013700e-02
   8.2052000e-02
   8.1961400e-02
   8.2007200e-02
   8.1984800e-02
   8.1999600e-02
   8.2041800e-02
   8.1990100e-02
   8.2014500e-02
   8.2008300e-02
   8.1980400e-02
   8.2000800e-02
   8.1988200e-02
   8.1979900e-02
   8.2003400e-02
   8.1921000e-02
   8.1985600e-02
   8.1995500e-02
   8.1951000e-02
   8.2006500e-02
   8.1977500e-02
   8.2005200e-02
   8.2000100e-02
   8.1938300e-02
   8.1993000e-02
   8.1983800e-02
   8.1995600e-02
   8.1992500e-02
   8.1976700e-02
   8.2020400e-02
   8.1986800e-02
   8.1990200e-02
   8.2007100e-02
   8.1957500e-02
   8.2021900e-02
   8.1954900e-02
   8.1995800e-02
   8.1993800e-02
   8.1992400e-02
   8.1970100e-02
   8.1989200e-02
   8.1998800e-02
   8.1991700e-02
   8.1970500e-02
   8.2000800e-02
   8.1938300e-02
   8.1965400e-02
   8.1985000e-02
   8.1930300e-02
   8.1970600e-02

---

the error is stated below.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.3\python learning files\python 2.7 DSP\read_the_input_signal_with_certain_frequency.py", line 65, in 
    y = butter_bandpass_filter(v_numbers, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=6)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.3\python learning files\python 2.7 DSP\read_the_input_signal_with_certain_frequency.py", line 14, in butter_bandpass_filter
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
  File "C:\WinPython-32bit-2.7.5.3\python-2.7.5\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\signaltools.py", line 565, in lfilter
    return sigtools._linear_filter(b, a, x, axis)

### ValueError: data type must provide an itemsize

Thanks

Comment: What does "I did something wrong..." mean?  Do you get an error message?  If so, what is it? (Please add it to the question.)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser  the error message has been added. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this part of the code:

```
f = open('NIRS_data.txt','r')
number_string = f.readline()
v_numbers = []
while number_string != '':
    numbers = number_string.split()
    for number in numbers:
        v_numbers.append( number )
    number_string = f.readline()
```

you haven't converted the fields to floating point values, so `v_numbers` is a list of strings.  The error occurs when you call `lfilter` with this list.

You could change the call to `append` to

```
        v_numbers.append(float(number))
```

If each row in the file has the same number of fields, a better solution is to completely replace the code that reads the file with a call to `np.loadtxt`.  That is,

```
v_numbers = np.loadtxt('NIRS_data.txt').ravel()
```